# Bias-Variance Tradeoff when using Oversampling Technique

Tags: machine-learning, oversampling, bias-variance-tradeoff, smote

Oversampling techniques (e.g. *SMOTE*) are often used when target values are not approximately equally represented.

How does this technique affect **bias and variance** of the predictive model that is trained on the resulting (*oversampled*) dataset?